# How to avoid duplicated roads?

Tags: qgis, export, road, quickosm

I am exporting a map as an svg into illustrator and finding there are many roads that are duplicated but in different layers, is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge them altogether and then remove duplicate geometries in qgis with `Delete duplicate geometries. This algorithm finds duplicated geometries and removes them.` It is in `Processing -> Toolbox` then search for Delete duplicate geometries.